# Putting a box around a Paragraph

Tags: overleaf

I've been looking around for coding to put a box around a paragraph in Latex but I can't seem to get any of them to work. I manage to get a box around the phrase, however it puts it on a single line that runs off the page. I try adding `\` in order pass parts of it to the next line, however it doesn't work. If I don't get that problem, then I get an error message saying "underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph lines 77-78". I have encountered this problem every single time and I normally end up just not putting a box around what I want. Any suggestions?

I am in exam mode, and I have tried `\fbox`, `\boxed`, `\makebox`, `\mbox`, `\parbox`, however none of them have been working.

With the `\parbox` I get the error "there is no line here to end", "missing number treated as 0" and "illegal unit of measure (pt inserted)".

Code:

```
\parbox[width=\textwidth]{\textbf{Proposition 2.1} \textit{Let $a$ and $b$ be positive integers with $a\leq b$ and let $p$ be a prime such that $p\not| ab$. Assume that $a\in\{1,2\}$. Then there exists a $t\in\Z$ with $1\leq t\leq\sqrt{2ab}$ such that $p\cdot t\in D_\Z(\langle 1, a, b, ab\rangle)$.}}\\
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please show us a short, compilable TeX code resulting in your issue, then we do not have to guess what you are doing ...

Comment: Welcome. // How many pages can be included in what you want, including paragraphs with at least one page break? // Are we talking about layout styling?

Comment: BTW, "overleaf" is not a relevant tag for your question, as you describe a LaTeX feature.

Comment: From where do you have that the syntax for `\parbox` is `\parbox[width=\textwidth]{....}` as that is not correct and will cause a compilation error. Plese don't just ignore compilation errors on Overleaf.

Comment: You may want to have a look at these packages: https://www.ctan.org/topic/box-breaking , at least, e.g. at framed .

Comment: Unrelated use `p \mid a` for `p` divides `a` and `\nmid` for `p \nmid a` (p does not divide a)

Answer (score 0):

Simple method is:

```
\usepackage{framed}

\begin{document}

\begin{framed}
...
....
....
\end{framed}
```

Answer (score 0):

Guessing that you want a framed box around a paragraph,this can be obtained perfectly with `\fbox` and `\parbox` but with the correct syntax.

I use dummy text instead of the example paragraph because other errors are unrelated with the question:

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum,parskip}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1][1-4]

\noindent\fbox{%
\parbox{\dimexpr%
    \linewidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule}%
    {\lipsum[2][1-4]}}

\lipsum[4][1-6]

\end{document}
```